# Код с деструктурированием Enum, помогите исправить

Tags: rust

Исправить код чтобы в качестве верного результата печатался индекс вектора с номером "3". Сейчас код выдает два результата "1" и "3":
[запустить код онлайн](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f170dce19974607a4ec49a32222edd20)

Подробнее о том какие критерии:

1. Переменная `find_me` имеет значение `Source::Base`, при итерациях вектора `Vec` должны бать отсеяны любые варианты с `Source::Curr` как не подходящие.
2. Найденный индекс в векторе должен быть с `word_2`.
3. Проверка соответствий по значению `i32` не требуется.

Другими словами, нужно исправить `match` (или заменить его на что-то другое, если есть такая замена), что выдаст индекс "3" вектора в качестве единственного верного результата по той причине, что только этот индекс совпадает с `find_me` по таким критериям как `Source::Base`и `word_2`.

```
pub enum Source {
    Curr(&'static str, i32),
    Base(&'static str, i32),
}

pub struct Data {
    field: Source,
}

fn main() {
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    let vec = vec![
        Data{field: Source::Curr("word", 1)},
        Data{field: Source::Curr("word_2", 2)},
        Data{field: Source::Base("word", 3)},
        Data{field: Source::Base("word_2", 4)},
    ];

    let find_me = Source::Base("word_2", 2);
    foo(find_me, vec);
}

fn foo(find_me: Source, vec: Vec<Data>) {
    let (name, _) = match find_me {
        Source::Base(x, y) => (x, y),
        Source::Curr(x, y) => (x, y),
    };
    let mut index = 0;
    for item in vec.into_iter() {
        match item {
            Data {
                field: Source::Curr(txt, _),
            } if name == txt => println!("{}", index),
            Data {
                field: Source::Base(txt, _),
            } if name == txt => println!("{}", index),
            _ => (),
        }
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Строго говоря, `find_me` имеет тип `Source`, но принимает значение с вариантом `Source::Base`.

Comment: Стоит уточнить постановку задачи, потому что угадывать ее из кода, который ее _не_ решает, достаточно затруднительно. Нужно искать по совпадению варианта `Current` и затем по равенству строки в первом значении в варианте, не обращая внимание на целочисленное значение?

Comment: *let find_me = Source::Base("word_2", 2)* соответствует третье по индексу позиции в переменной *Vec*  (проверка значения i32 не требуется). 
Match должен выдать результат, печатающий верный индекс в векторе (т.е. "3") опираясь на два совпадения:

1. Совпадение значений в векторе и в find_me по общему "word_2" (при этом проверка значения i32 не требуется);

2. Совпадение по Source::Base

Comment: Дал нормальное описание в теме, спасибо что указали (мне было не очевидно до этого, что я плохо описал условия )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вам следует написать следующую функцию:

```
fn variant_eq<T>(first: &T, second: &T) -> bool {
    std::mem::discriminant(first) == std::mem::discriminant(second)
}
```

Или вот такую:

```
fn variant_eq(a: &Source, b: &Source) -> bool {
    match (a, b) {
        (&Source::Base(..), &Source::Base(..)) => true,
        (&Source::Curr(..), &Source::Curr(..)) => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

И использовать ее при сравнении:

```
match item {
            Data {
                field: Source::Curr(txt, _),
            } if name == txt && variant_eq(&item.field, &find_me) => {
                println!("{}", index)
            }
            Data {
                field: Source::Base(txt, _),
            } if name == txt && variant_eq(&item.field, &find_me) => {
                println!("{}", index)
            }
            _ => (),
        }
```

Первая, конечно, предпочтительней, так как она шаблонна, но вторая нагляднее, поэтому решил привести и ее.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек! И отдельно благодарю за приведенный второй вариант variant_eq, дающий мне понимание.